# First Order Logic Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I have the following problem I'm trying to understand/solve using first order logic.

```
Predicates:
Set(S), which states that S is a set, and
x ∈ S, which states that x is an element of S,
```

Using first order logic, I need to write :

```
For any x and y, there is a set containing just the elements x and y.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w$ is a set containing just the elements $x$ and $y$, then $z\in w$ iff $z=x$ or $z=y$. So desired formula is

$$\forall x\forall y \exists z\forall w: \mathrm{Set}(z)\land (w\in z \leftrightarrow (w=x)\lor (w=y))$$

Comment: Easier to work with, more intuitive might be: $$\forall x\forall y \exists z:(Set(z) \land \forall w: (w\in z \leftrightarrow (w=x)\lor (w=y)))$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

What is a set containing just $x$ and $y$? It's the set $\{x,y\}$.

First write a formula $\varphi(x,y,z)$ which states that $z=\{x,y\}$. Next, quantify over $x,y,z$ according to your instructions.